# jquery - how to enable this image - age slider

Tags: jquery, html

[image]

I was looking for advise on how to enable the above image to work in jquery.

I have the two numbers of either side:

```
<span id="startAge">21</span>
<span id="endAge">99</span>
```

I can split the image up so the bar and the icons are separate.

Questions:

- How would I get the icon to slide along the bar?
- How would I get the age to change as the icon slides?
- How can I prevent the bars crossing - eg: aged: 35 to 30 (being the wrong way around)?

Any other advise would be great - just need a hand to get started on this one.

Thanks

Comment: You need the [jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the [jqueryui slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range) like Zoltan mentioned.  you can get the functionality you need through css and getting used to the slider api calls.

Comment: if jqueryui is not an option to add to your solution's javascript libraries, then please add a bit more html to your question :)